# Rails Action Cable scroll down after message posting

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, actioncable

I configured action cable, now I would like to use the following js function

```
$('.scroll-bar').scrollTop(row);
```

to scroll down the chat after submitting a message

[image: Action Cable Chat]

So I tried to include the previous code in both `app/assets/channels/messages.js` and `app/assets/javascripts/room.js`.

The problem is until after I execute `app/assets/channels/messages.js` the html does not have then new `<p></p>` tag appended.

```
App.messages = App.cable.subscriptions.create('MessagesChannel', {  
  received: function(data) {
    $("#messages").removeClass('hidden')
    return $('#messages').append(this.renderMessage(data));
  },
  renderMessage: function(data) {
    return "<p> <b>" + data.user + ": </b>" + data.message + "</p>";
  }
});
```

This are my chat messages, I can not run `.scrollTop(row)` on a row that does not still exist.

I tested and the `<p>` tags are added after `messages.js`.

[image: ptags]

I found a temporary solution to solve this, by commenting return from  `return $('#messages').append(this.renderMessage(data));` and calling after the `.scrollTop(row)` method. The solution works, but this way only the html is appended to the page without `<p>` tags.. Somehow `renderMessage` is not working properly.

I am available for any info

Thanks a lot
Fabrizio Bertoglio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my temporary solution, not working correctly, because like this I will not append a `<p>` tag but just the text.

Basically like this the I am just appending the html without 
`"<p> <b>" + data.user + ": </b>" + data.message + "</p>"`

You can see from the picture below that the message is not inside `<p>` tags.

[image: HTML Example]

This is what I have done, I commented the return to execute the `.scrollTop()` function after `$('#messages').append(this.renderMessage(data))`;

`app/assets/channels/messages.js`

```
App.messages = App.cable.subscriptions.create('MessagesChannel', {  
  received: function(data) {
    $("#messages").removeClass('hidden');
    $('#messages').append(this.renderMessage(data));
    height = $('.scroll-bar')[0].scrollHeight;
    $('.scroll-bar').scrollTop(height);
    /*return $('#messages').append(this.renderMessage(data));*/
  },
  renderMessage: function(data) {
    return "<p> <b>" + data.user + ": </b>" + data.message + "</p>";
  }
});
```

I think the solution is [hear](https://blog.heroku.com/real_time_rails_implementing_websockets_in_rails_5_with_action_cable), from this post I followed to implement action cable, I don't understand who is directly calling the `received: function(data) {}`

is it the callback method `subscribed` inside `messages_channel.rb`?

```
class MessagesChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel 
    def subscribed
        stream_from 'messages'
    end 
end
```

I don't have a clear idea how this `callback` method is calling the other method and how is the application flow.

[Heroku Action Cable](https://blog.heroku.com/real_time_rails_implementing_websockets_in_rails_5_with_action_cable)
[image]